# boost regex cyrillic

Tags: регулярные-выражения, boost, кириллица

Подскажите, `boost::regex` с латиницей работает хорошо, а кириллицу не распознает. Нужна поддержка кириллицы.

Comment: Может стоит использовать юникодные строки?

Comment: я использую юникодные строки

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "boost/regex.hpp"
#include <locale>
using namespace std;
int main(int argc, const char** argv)
{
    std::string str( "новый дом, новый дом новый дом" );
    boost::regex regx;
    regx.imbue(std::locale("russian"));
    regx.assign("(\\w+)\\s+(\\w+)");
    std::cout << "Search string: " << str << ", pattern: " << regx.str() <<  
std::endl;


    std::string format( "$1 красный $2");
    cout << "regex_replace: " << regex_replace( str, regx, format ) <<  
std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: если попытаться задать локаль в imbue, получается ошибка компиляции. boost::basic_regex<charT,traits>::imbue' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'std::locale' to 'unsigned int. использую boost::wregex